# Apple XCode Self-Extractor

Tags: xcode

Im trying to make a file that will unzip a file and place the contents in the correct location.  I need the contents of a ZIP file to be unzipped to 
    ~/Library/Application Support/Contents.
How do I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unzip` command line tool, launched with a `NSTask` would do the job.

```
NSArray* arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjets:@"Path/to/your/zip/file", @"-d", @"~/Library/Application Support/Your_App/", nil];
[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:@"usr/bin/unzip" arguments:arguments];
```

Comment: That's on the Mac, iOS it a bit different.